# WCF: Cannot import WSDL with Security Binding

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to call a SOAP-service from my ,net code. But when I  import the wsdl I get the following error:

> Cannot import wsdl:port
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.bipro.net/namespace']/wsdl:binding[@name='KrankenServiceBinding']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.bipro.net/namespace']/wsdl:service[@name='KrankenService_2.6.0.1.1']/wsdl:port[@name='KrankenService']
>   Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy import extension.
>   Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElementImporter
>   Error: An unsupported security policy assertion was detected during the security policy import: https://example.com/SecurityTokenService
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.bipro.net/namespace']/wsdl:binding[@name='KrankenServiceBinding']

I tried it initially with .NET Core but also with the classic Framework. Same result.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider? If the error occurred in DotNetFramework too, I think there is something wrong with the WSDL file. one more thing needs to mention is that there are two kinds of WSDL file that WCF generally published.

> http://localhost:11000/Service1.svc?wsdl
>   http://localhost:11000/Service1.svc?singleWsdl

The **?singleWSDL** file contains all schemas that imported from an external file., such as Data Contract. It is normally applicable for the invocation from SOAPUI.
The **?WSDL** file usually is used to generate the client proxy to call the service.
Have you tried another WSDL file? Besides, please try to call the service with a client proxy created by using **?WSDL** file.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.